# probability scenario question

Tags: probability

I have been struggling with these question a couple of days now and i don't know what to do. The question is this one below:
Suppose that I go to the beach, and when I arrive at the sand the beach is empty
and the edge of the sea is 10 meters away. To decide where to sit I throw a stone
directly towards the water: it lands between me and the sea and for x ∈ (0, 10) the
probability I throw the stone at least x meters is

$$\frac{(10+2x)(10-x)^2}{1000}$$
After I sit
on the sand at the place the stone lands, my child chooses a place to sit uniformly at
random between me and the sea.
What is the probability that my child sits within $2$ meters of the sea?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! What have you tried? Have you tried formalizing the problem with conditional probabilities?

Comment: I thought about using conditional probability but i can't find the joint density function of this 2 events to proceed

Comment: Did you mean to write $(10 + 2x)(10 - x)^{2}/1000$?

Comment: Sorry i just fixed the mistake

Comment: well i don't know! i was given this question and i'd like some help to answer it cause i'm lost

Comment: The comments on this question are incorrect and very confusing for the OP. The function given by the OP is correct - it is clearly stated to be the probability the stone is thrown **at least** x meters and it is not the pdf as people commenting seem to assume.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to find the p.d.f. It is $$f(x)=\frac{60x-6x^2}{1000}.$$

When the stone is thrown a distance $x\le 8$ the probability the child sits within 2 meters of the sea is $\frac{2}{10-x}.$ So the probability you require is 
$$\int_0^8 \frac{2f(x)}{10-x}\text dx+\int_8^{10} f(x)\text dx$$
$$=\int_0^8 \frac{12x}{1000}\text dx+0.104=0.488$$

This is an outline of what you need to do so ask if there's anything here you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Given,

$$P(X>=x) = \frac{1}{1000}(10+2x)(10-x)^2$$

This yields a probability density function of:

$$p.d.f = \frac{dP(X<=x)}{dx} = \frac{60x-6x^2}{1000}$$

The probability that the child sits within 2m will depend on where x is. This can be expressed in the conditional form as below:

$$P(child < 2m) = P(child < 2m | x < 8m).P(x < 8m) + P(child < 2m | x > 8m).P(x > 8m)$$

Clearly, if x is more than 8m, then the resultant probability is 1 (child has to sit within 2m in that case). Thus, the above can be simplified as:

$$P(child < 2m) = P(child < 2m \text{ and } x < 8m) + P(x > 8m)$$

**Second term in the RHS:** This is simply the integral of the probability distribution:

$$\frac{1}{1000}\int_{8}^{10}(60x-6x^2) = 0.104$$

**First term in the RHS:** To solve this, realise that with a uniform distribution and a given x,

$$P(child < 2m | x) = \frac{2}{(10-x)}$$

Thus, the probability that the stone is thrown at a distance of x **AND** the child sits at dist < 2m is simply,

$$P(child < 2m \text{ and }  x) = P(child < 2m | x).P(x)$$
which is,
$$P(child < 2m \text{ and }  x) = \frac{2}{1000}.6x$$
Thus, the total probability of the above when x < 8m is:
$$P(child < 2m \text{ and } x < 8m) = \frac{2}{1000}\int_{0}^{8}6x = 0.384$$

Thus, combining the 2 steps:
$$P(child < 2m) = 0.384 + 0.104 = 0.488 = 49\% \text{ (approx.) }$$